# Usage of dup2()

Tags: linux, unix, gnu, file-descriptor

```c
dup2(fd, 0);
dup2(fd, 1);
dup2(fd, 2);
if (fd > 2)
  close(fd);
```

According to the book Advanced Programming in the UNIX environment, the if statement above is necessary. The book suggests to work through it by considering what would happen if fd = 1 in one case, and if fd = 3 in another.

If fd = 1, 0 (stdin) would be closed and then would point at stdout, 1 would still point at stdout (since dup2() doesn't close a file descriptor if it's equal to the first argument, and will return 1) and 2 would point at stdout.

If fd = 3, every file descriptor would be first closed and then point at whatever file 3 points at.

Why is it necessary to close the descriptor if it's greater than 2?

Comment: By doing this series of fd manipulations, you're trying to achieve some goal state. Does the goal state include an extra copy of stdin/stdout/stderr on some higher fd?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley There's no further context to the question other than the code snippet in the question, and the question as to why the if statement is necessary.

Comment: Do you think there is *any* context where a reasonable goal state would be "there's an extra file descriptor, sometimes, depending on what file descriptor number we started with"?

Comment: It doesn't seem like having an extra descriptor to be a particularly pressing issue after duplicating the descriptor 3 times, so I'm thinking there must be some other issue at play - by the end of it, we have 4 descriptors all pointing at the same file table entry, what good does closing the original do, as there's still redundancy?

Comment: @bag I've added an explanation of why it's important to close unused descriptors to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to leave any unused file descriptors open. After you redirect `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` to `fd`, you're not planning on using `fd` by itself -- it was just opened temporarily so that you could then duplicate all the standard descriptors to it. So you need to close it.

But you don't want to close it if it's actually the same as `stdin`, `stdout`, or `stderr` (this should be unlikely, but it's possible if one of them was already closed before you opened `fd`). So you need the `if` to prevent that.

As to why it's important to close the original descriptor, some types of streams do something special (and often important) only when *all* of the descriptors referring to it are closed. For instance, a TCP connection will not be closed until all the descriptors are closed, a deleted file will only have its data removed from disk when all links are removed and all descriptors are closed, and the read end of a pipe only receives EOF when all the descriptors referring to the write end are closed. So if you leave `fd` open, and later close the standard descriptors, it will prevent this final action from occurring.

A very common situation where you need to close a descriptor is when you create a pipe to communicate with a child process. The code generally looks something like:

```
pipe(fds);
switch (fork()) {
    case 0: // child
        dup2(fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fds[0]);
        close(fds[1]);
        execlp("program", "program", "arg1", (char*)NULL);
        break;
    case -1: // error
        perror("fork");
        exit(-1);
        break;
    default: // parent
        close(fds[0]);
        // Code that writes to fds[1]
}
```

The child needs to close the write end of the pipe (`fds[1]`), otherwise the child won't receive EOF when the parent closes it.

Comment: That's an interesting (and very insightful, thanks!) detail about closing the original descriptor, however, its not mentioned in the book so I'd be inclined to think it may not be the answer here.

Comment: The book mentions that the code snippet is a commonly seen, so the example when the process forks might be the answer.

Comment: @bag Forking doesn't usually dup all 3 descriptors. The pattern in your example is common in generic network servers like `xinetd`.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `dup2` call is to copy the first file descriptor to the second.  So after the three calls to `dup2`, file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 are open and are copies of file descriptor `fd`.  The subsequent call to `close` then closes the original file descriptor.

If you didn't check `fd > 2` prior to calling `close(fd)`, then you would be closing one of the file descriptors you just opened.  For example, if `fd` was 2 then `close(fd)` is the same as `close(2)`.

It doesn't make to close a file descriptor right after opening it and not doing anything with it.  That's why the check is necessary.

Comment: Does dup2() not copy the second argument to the first? Ah okay, I had understood that much, but I thought there was something more complex to the question that I wasn't understanding, since there's no real context to the code.

Comment: No, dup2() copes the first argument to the second. The only other thing to consider is that normally stdin/out/err is already open, that means if `fd` is the result of e.g. opening a file, its value would then never be <= 2, and the check might seem superfluous. But the code tries to account for all things, including that someone just passed in stdin  as  the `fd` , or e.g. closed stdin (which is descriptor 0) and then opened a file - in that case the descriptor in `fd` would be given the value 0 as that's the lowest available descriptor if stdin was closed.

Answer (score 0):

The point is not to close `fd` if it is greater than 2; rather it is to not close `fd` if it is one of the standard streams. In your example, closing `1` (stdout) would clearly be incorrect.

But the additional file descriptor does need to be closed. When an executable starts, it is entitled to believe that only fds 0, 1 and 2 are in use, so it is important to clean up -- close -- fds before `exec`ing. The close-on-exec flag is another useful option.

Comment: Ah the close-on-exec flag is cleared for the second argument after using dup2(), right? And that's why we should explicitly close it?